# Multirow text disappears behind cell

Tags: tables, multirow, xltabular

I wanted to use multirow, but the text of it disappears between the first cell.

[image: The error]

Here is my table

```
%multi-row
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{
      | >{\columncolor[gray]{.8}\centering\arraybackslash}X 
      | >{\centering\arraybackslash}X 
      | >{\centering\arraybackslash}X|}
      \caption{User Stories}
      \hline
      \rowcolor[gray]{.8}
      \textbf{User story} & \textbf{Task} & \textbf{Estimering}
      \hline
      \endfirsthead
      \hline
      \multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{\small \tablename\ \thetable, fortsat} \\[1ex]
      \hline
      \rowcolor[gray]{.8}
      \textbf{User story} & \textbf{Estimering} & \textbf{Beskrivelse}
      \hline
      \endhead
      \hline
      \multicolumn{3}{r}{\small \tablename\ \thetable, forsætter på næste side\ldots}
      \endfoot
      \endlastfoot
      \multirow{4}{*}{\textbf{Som bruger ønsker jeg at kunne være tilknyttet et hold}}& 0&\\ \cline{2-3}
      & 1 &\\ \cline{2-3}  
      & 2 &\\  \cline{2-3}
      & 3 &\\  \cline{2-3}
      \hline
      \textbf{Som bruger som er admin ønsker jeg at kunne oprette valgfags liste} & x &  
      \hline
      \textbf{Som bruger som er student ønsker jeg at kunne prioterer valgfag} & x &  
      \hline
      \textbf{Som bruger ønsker jeg at kunne logge ind med mit skole login} & x & 
      \hline
      \textbf{Som bruger ønsker jeg at kunne hente information fra skolen} & x &  
      \hline
      \textbf{Som bruger ønsker jeg at systemet skal kunne lave endelige hold ud fra de studerendes prioteter} & x & 
      \hline
      \textbf{Som bruger ønsker jeg at systemet skal kunne begrænse hvornår de studerende kan sætter deres prioteter} & x &   
      \hline
\end{xltabular}
```

I saw some people in previous answers say to insert the multirow at the end of the line but that made the text span across the whole table instead of only the first cell.

Answer (score 1):

If you willing to use `tabularray` package instead of `tabularx`, than table code is more clean and shorter:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}             % for dummy text

\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption}


\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-2]
    \begingroup
\DefTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{normal}{\tablename\ \thetable, forsætter på næste side\ldots}
\SetTblrTemplate{contfoot-text}{normal}
\DefTblrTemplate{conthead-text}{normal}{(fortsat)}
\SetTblrTemplate{conthead-text}{normal}
\SetTblrStyle{contfoot-text}{font=\footnotesize\sffamily\itshape, fg=gray5}
\begin{longtblr}[
caption = {User Stories},
  label = {tab:user-stories}
                ]{hlines, vlines,
                  colspec = {X[2, j, font=\bfseries, bg=gray8] 
                             X[c] X[c]},
                  row{1}  = {font=\bfseries, bg=gray8},
                  rowhead  = 1
                  }
User story  &   Task    &   Estimering      \\
%
\SetCell[r=4]{} Som bruger ønsker jeg at kunne være tilknyttet et hold  
            & 0         &                   \\
            & 1         &                   \\
            & 2         &                   \\
            & 3         &                   \\
Som bruger som er admin ønsker jeg at kunne oprette valgfags liste                                     
            & x         &                   \\
Som bruger som er student ønsker jeg at kunne prioterer valgfag
            & x         &                   \\
Som bruger ønsker jeg at kunne logge ind med mit skole login
            & x         &                   \\
Som bruger ønsker jeg at kunne hente information fra skolen
            & x         &                   \\
Som bruger ønsker jeg at systemet skal kunne lave endelige hold ud fra de studerendes prioteter
            & x         &                   \\
Som bruger ønsker jeg at systemet skal kunne begrænse hvornår de studerende kan sætter deres prioteter
            & x         &                   \\
\end{longtblr}
    \endgroup
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Move `\multirow` from the top to the bottom of all merges cells. Then, use a negative argument as a number of merged cells. Using colours with `multirow` package is one of the commons issues and is already explained in [documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/multirow).

I also changed the argument `{*}` to `{=}`. The result is long texts will get line breaks. The argument `{=}` maintains paragraph cells, such as `p{}`, which is the case here because `X` is the `p{<len>}`-type with `<len>` being calculated behind the scenes.

Your code has multiple syntax errors. You should consider installing a good editor that can highlights typos, mistakes, or even points at missing components.

Here's the working code:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}


\begin{document}
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{
    | >{\columncolor[gray]{.8}\centering\arraybackslash}X
    | >{\centering\arraybackslash}X
    | >{\centering\arraybackslash}X |
  }
  \caption{User Stories}\label{tab:user-stories} \\ \hline
  \rowcolor[gray]{.8}
  \textbf{User story}
  & \textbf{Task}
  & \textbf{Estimering} \\
  \hline
  \endfirsthead
  \multicolumn{3}{@{}l}{%
    \small \tablename\ \thetable, fortsat%
    \vspace{\abovecaptionskip}   % <-- in case you want maintain the same skip between caption and the table
  } \\ \hline
  \rowcolor[gray]{.8}
  \textbf{User story}                                                                                              & \textbf{Estimering} & \textbf{Beskrivelse} \\ \hline
  \endhead
  \multicolumn{3}{r}{\small \tablename\ \thetable, forsætter på næste side\ldots}
  \endfoot
                                                                                                                   & 0  & \\ \cline{2-3}
                                                                                                                   & 1  & \\ \cline{2-3}
                                                                                                                   & 2  & \\ \cline{2-3}
  \multirow{-4}{=}{\centering\textbf{Som bruger ønsker jeg at kunne være tilknyttet et hold}} & 3  & \\ \hline
  \textbf{Som bruger som er admin ønsker jeg at kunne oprette valgfags liste}                                      & x  & \\ \hline
  \textbf{Som bruger som er student ønsker jeg at kunne prioterer valgfag}                                         & x  & \\ \hline
  \textbf{Som bruger ønsker jeg at kunne logge ind med mit skole login}                                            & x  & \\ \hline
  \textbf{Som bruger ønsker jeg at kunne hente information fra skolen}                                             & x  & \\ \hline
  \textbf{Som bruger ønsker jeg at systemet skal kunne lave endelige hold ud fra de studerendes prioteter}         & x  & \\ \hline
  \textbf{Som bruger ønsker jeg at systemet skal kunne begrænse hvornår de studerende kan sætter deres prioteter}  & x  & \\ \hline
\end{xltabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]